# Concatenate results of multiple API calls - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, api

My apologies as I am very new to javascript and inexperienced so my code is very rudimentary, and I'll do the best I can at explaining myself.

I'm making a call to an API to get a blob which I then convert to base64. I can then pass this base64 string to a seperate script within the .map array - so this makes multiple calls to my script. But what I want to do is to concatenate the base64 strings into one string and pass a single call the my script.

I understand that this is asynchronous and I probably need some callbacks but im unsure how to do this in my case. Essentially I would like to make the 'base64data_1' variable within the reader.onloadend function available outside of the .map array, but the reader.onloadend function is the last action performed.

```
function getPhoto() {

    const root = 'https://public-api.konectech.com/PROD/api/';

    var acc = document.getElementById("accID").value;

    var photoId1 = document.getElementById("photoID1").value;
    var photoId2 = document.getElementById("photoID2").value;
    var photoId3 = document.getElementById("photoID3").value;

    var root1 = (root + acc + "/attachment/id/overlay/")

    let uri = [root1 + photoId1,root1 + photoId2,root1 + photoId3];

    let filenames = [photoId1,photoId2,photoId3];

    var base64Array = [];

    let base64 = uri.map (function (url) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "image/jpg");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("x-api-key", "xxxxxxxx");
        xhr.responseType = "blob";

        xhr.send();

        xhr.onload = function (data, filename, mime) {

        var filename = (url.slice(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) );

        const blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: mime || 'application/octet-stream'});

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);  
        reader.onloadend = function() {

            var base64data = reader.result;

            const base64data_1 = (base64data.slice(base64data.lastIndexOf(',') + 1) );

            //console.log([base64data_1]);

            base64Array = base64data_1;

            console.log([base64Array]);

            return [base64Array];

            };
        }

    });
    //console.log([base64Array]);
}
```

I was hoping that if i could get access pass the 'base64data_1' variable as an array I could then use promise.all and .join get the desired result similar to below:

```
function getPhoto() {

    var array =['test_1','test_2','test_3','test_4','test_5'];

    var items = [];

    let newArray = array.map (function (array_1) {

        items = array_1 + '_appended';
        console.log(items);
        return [items];     
    })

    console.log(newArray);

    Promise.all(newArray)
        .then( function (arrayOfValues) {
        console.log(arrayOfValues.join(","));   // returns test_1_appended,test_2_appended,test_3_appended,test_4_appended,test_5_appended
      })
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Comment: Thanks of the link @palaѕн. So far I think I am making what I think is a callout so that my base64data_1 variable is available in a function outside of .map. However this function is still invoked from within .map so I still receive separate responses rather than a single string with array. I will keep researching the link you provided. Thank you

Comment: I read all the information in the link, unfortunately I'm still unable to successfully pass the 'base64data_1' variable result outside of the .map iterator. Would anyone know if its possible to chain the functions for xhr.onload and where I declare the reader.onloadend (instead of nesting them)? Hope that makes sense